# Google Analytics Reporting API - Get Activity with User ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't get User Activity from the Google Analytics Reporting API (v4) using a User ID.

Client ID (in a different, non-User ID view) works, however.

Am I missing something?

--

**For Client ID**

I go here in my Google Analytics web interface:

[https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-user-activity/a45743608w76484324p**79062844**/_u.date00=**20190327**&_u.date01=**20190402**&_r.userId=**1142688158.1525244974**](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-user-activity/a45743608w76484324p79062844/_u.date00=20190327&_u.date01=20190402&_r.userId=1142688158.1525244974)

I get user activity details as expected:
[image: Google Analytics web interface using Client ID]

--

I call the following:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/userActivity:search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
  "viewId": "79062844",
  "dateRange": {
     "startDate": "2019-03-27",
     "endDate": "2019-04-02"
  },
   "user": {
     "type": "CLIENT_ID",
     "userId": "1142688158.1525244974"
  }
}
```

I get the expected response:

```
{
  "sessions": [
    …
  ],
  "totalRows": 14,
  "sampleRate": 1
}
```

--

**For User ID**

I go here in my Google Analytics web interface:

[https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-user-activity/a45743608w76484324p**185098721**/_u.date00=**20190327**&_u.date01=**20190402**&_r.userId=**Not%20Logged%20In-**](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-user-activity/a45743608w76484324p185098721/_u.date00=20190327&_u.date01=20190402&_r.userId=Not%20Logged%20In-)

I get user activity details as expected:
[image: Google Analytics web interface using User ID]

--

I call the following:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/userActivity:search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
  "viewId": "185098721",
  "dateRange": {
     "startDate": "2019-03-27",
     "endDate": "2019-04-02"
  },
   "user": {
     "type": "USER_ID",
     "userId": "Not Logged In-"
  }
}
```

I get **an error instead**:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "USER_ID: Not Logged In- not found.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

--

I have tried different IDs, different dates, changing the type to CLIENT_ID, URL encoding the User ID, and User IDs with no spaces - no joy.

Comment: Here's the documentation on the API endpoint in question:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

Comment: Why are you sending an API key this is private data you should be sending an access token.

Comment: @DaImTo: The above examples are using the APIs Explorer and, when functioning, we will be making the calls server-side (C# .NET Core). But you are 100% correct, any client-side API calls must use access tokens.

Comment: Considering that I wrote the .net examples on the official site I am glad that you have confirmed my statement.

Comment: The API is telling you that the user didnt exist what do you expect to see?  please include your snippet where you are sending the userid

Comment: I've added screenshots for clarity.

Comment: @DaImTo: I'd expect to see the sessions for that User ID listed as I do when using a Client ID on a non-User ID view. The snippet where I'm sending the User ID is the second code block under the "For User ID" heading in the above question.

Comment: Ok you win that looks weird i sent an email to the team at Google I cant promise you will hear anything here but if i do i will let you know.  You might also want to submit a bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400

Comment: They are looking into it

Comment: @DaImTo: Thanks for all your help, mate!! I have submitted a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130161158

Comment: Current option is that the api may not be able to handle userid's with a space.   they may update the docs. If i hear anything else i will let you know.  I will ping them with your issue

Comment: @Akaoni is there any update.?

Comment: @NIshamMahsin Unfortunately not - still waiting on Google for a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is indeed a bug which several others are also experiencing.

This bug can be +1'd and followed here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130161158

**Edit:** This has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From your URL, you are looking for an ID called `Not%20Logged%20In-` which is not a valid id.  Its probably changing the id when you copy paste the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  
  
The documentation says that the User ID can be text of any length:  
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId  
That said, I have tried User IDs with just hex values (e.g. "55d28a097d822306603eb942") with the same result.  
  
To clarify, the URLs work fine, it is the API that isn't returning User Activity when utilising User IDs.

Comment: Hmm, ok so its lots of users under this ID?  The body of your request looks fine, I suspect its the API not being able to handle the spaces as thats the only thing different from my userId hits, and is unusual I would say.  Its URL encoded in the web UI only I guess.  Can you try with a normal userId format like "not-logged-in" ?

Comment: I have tried with no spaces (or hyphens), but still get the error. E.g. "USER_ID: 55d28a097d822306603eb942 not found."